# After appending a select option and selecting the appended option alert shows undefined + Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie with Jquery and i am trying to append an select option. This works and when i select the newly added option in the select. I am getting undefined in alert.

```
var selects = $(this).closest('div').find('.accSelectandlookup') ;

//Check if the accid is already present in the selectoptions and if not then add  

if (!selects.find('option[value="' + accid + '"]').length) {
alert(accid); // This throws up the correct value
selects.append('<option value="' + accid + '">Attach to Existing : ' + accname + '</option>');
}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

```
selects.change(function(){

alert('selected value is ' +  selects.filter(":selected").val()); // This throws undefined
})
```

Comment: log selects in console and make sure that you get the select element properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `$(this).val(`) to get the selected `option` value of current `select`. The `selects` might not be available when `change` event is fired due to variable scope.

```
selects.change(function(){
    alert('selected value is ' + $(this).val()); // This throws undefined
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you load the `.change()` function, it reads the current DOM.

When you `append`, it's changing the DOM, but that doesn't update what `.change()` is looking at. So you need to modify it like so...

```
$('body').change(function(){
    alert('blah');
}, '.accSelectandlookup');
```

This keeps `.change()` LIVE, using the current DOM.